# Implicit processor for all subtypes

Tags: scala, covariance, implicit

I have some types

```
trait Processor[+A] {
  def handle[B >: A](a: B): Unit
}

trait TypeA

case class A1() extends TypeA
```

and a method

```
def process[A](a: A)(implicit processor: Processor[A])
```

can I have something like

```
implicit val processor = new Processor[TypeA] {
  def handle[B >: TypeA](a: B): Unit = {
    println(a)
  }
}
```

so that it will handle all subtype of `TypeA`? e.g.

```
process(A1())
```

but in my case it just gives

```
scala> process(A1())
<console>:29: error: could not find implicit value for parameter processor: Processor[A1]
              process(A1())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What covariance does is precisely the opposite: it means that a `Processor[A1]` is a `Processor[TypeA]`, so a processor for a type can handle all its supertypes.

So if you need a `Processor` to handle all subtypes of a type instead, you need contravariance. And your trait looks exactly like it should in fact be contravariant (but this may be due to simplification for the question):

```
trait Processor[-A] {
  def handle(a: A): Unit
}

implicit val processor: Processor[TypeA] = new Processor[TypeA] {
  def handle(a: TypeA): Unit = {
    println(a)
  }
}
```

Then `process(A1())` works.